# trying to input escaped hex chars in python

Tags: python, input, encode

I am writing a script to test serial comms link and I want to enter an escaped sequence from the keyboard into the script like \xB6\xB7.  I think my problem is a lack of understanding of strings.  Here's a console sequence of a test I was doing to try and understand how it all works:

```
test = '\x69\x6A\x6B'

type(test)

<class 'str'>

len(test)

3

print(str.encode(test))

b'ijk'                      # this is the kind of result I want

test = input('?')

?\x69\x6A\x6B

type(test)

<class 'str'>

len(test)

12                          # why is this length 12 not 3 as above?

print(str.encode(test))

b'\\x69\\x6A\\x6B'          # this is not what I want
```

Forgive the noob question.  I have tried using bytes instead of `str.encode` but same result.  I have managed to write a program with serial comms using pyserial so I am not completely stupid, honest!

Answer (score 2):

when you input it as `input()` it will automatically escape the backslash to `\\`

so to fix it first convert to bytes

```
test_bytes = test.encode('utf8')
```

then you can decode it and tell python that the `\\`  should be interpretted as unicode escape

```
actual_answer = test_bytes.decode("unicode-escape")
# 'ijk'
```

Comment: Thanks Joran, I think your first sentence solved the riddle in my head!